# Streamci Visual C++ error

Tags: windows-7, rundll

I have a problem that looks easy but is not as it seems. In short, it looks as if I am missing some redist dlls. Up until recently this wasn't an issue. Now programs that ran before choose not too. Reinstall the redist right ? Well, that isn't working.

**What I've tried**:

- Installing the directx, c++, .net redists packs
- Uninstalled and re-installed software
- Ran CCleaner registry cleaner

I am running **Windows 7 home sp1**. I have installed every redist pack I could google and still I am running into this issue. I un-installed and re-installed these problematic programs several times and nothing worked.

I am going to attach a screenshot of my nvidia drivers trying to update, however, this problem happens with other programs as well. I am at wits' end on this, I've tried all the basic remedies with no result.

**Window 1:**

"*There was a problem starting streamci*" 
"*The specified module could not be found*"

**Window 2:**

"Runtime Error!
Program: C:\User\\AppData\Local\Temp\NVIDIA\Displ...

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information"

Answer (score 0):

#### There was a problem starting streamci" "The specified module could not be found

> I get a message box titled RunDll that says "there was a problem starting streamci.  The specified module could not be found."

...

> **Streamci.dll is used in the default Windows audio driver which is installed on your computer to handle the sound & audio on your system**. It is one of the most commonly used .dll (dynamic link library) files on Windows, which leads it to post a series of errors if it ever becomes damaged or corrupted.
>
> Since this file is used by Windows to control the use and installation of audio drivers, it would be logical to attempt to repair of any these files first. You can do this by following these steps:
>
> For Windows 7
>
> 1. Click “Start” > Control Panel > Hardware and Sound
> 2. Under “Devices and Printers” heading, click Device Manager
> 3. In the Window that opens, look for the speaker icon next to “Sound, video and game controllers”
> 4. Expand this option then right click on the erroneous hardware (should have a yellow exclamation mark next to it)
> 5. Click properties and go to “Driver“. Now click “Update Driver” and follow the on screen wizard

...

> Perform SFC (System File Checker) scan and see if the issue occurs.
>
> Use the [System File Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) tool to troubleshoot missing or
> corrupted system files on Windows Vista or on Windows 7

...

Source [there was a problem starting streamci](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/there-was-a-problem-starting-streamci/9baa642c-bc2f-41f3-b610-50d054856808)

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Here is the output from that scan.       Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: Did you check your audio driver?

Comment: Yes. At least twice. I installed the drivers twice.